# MongoDB Match and Slice multiple child arrays

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I currently have this schema

```
var dataSchema = new Schema({
hid: { type: String },
sensors: [{
    nid: { type: String },
    sid: { type: String },
    data: {
        param1: { type: String },
        param2: { type: String },
        data: { type: String }
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
actuators: [{
    nid: { type: String },
    aid: { type: String },
    control_id: { type: String },
    data: {
        param1: { type: String },
        param2: { type: String },
        data: { type: String }
    },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
status: [{
    nid: {type: String},
    status_code: {type: String},
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}],
updated: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
created: { type: Date }
});
```

The query that I'm trying to build should search the schema by "hid", then only pick from the "sensors", "actuators" and "status" arrays the objects that match the `nid` that i provide and then also limit the result to 10 element for each array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, don't use multiple pipeline phases when "one" will do. Every pipeline stage you include is effectively adding "time" to processing since it's another pass through the data.

So what logically works in a "single" stage, should stay in a "single" stage:

```
Data.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "hid": hid } },
    { "$project": {
        "sensors": {
            "$slice": [
                { "$filter": { 
                    "input": "$sensors", 
                    "as": "sensor", 
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$sensor.nid", nid ] } 
                }},
                -10
            ]
        },
        "actuators": {
            "$slice": [
                { "$filter": { 
                    "input": "$actuators", 
                    "as": "actuator", 
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$actuator.nid", nid ] } 
                }},
                -10
            ]
        },
        "status": {
            "$slice": [
                { "$filter": { 
                    "input": "$status", 
                    "as": "status", 
                    "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$status.nid", nid ] } 
                }},
                -10
            ]
        },
        "updated": 1,
        "created": 1
    }}
])
```

Also, it's not necessary to use `"_id": 1` in inclusions since `"_id"` is **always** included unless explicitly "excluded".

The main case is to try not to create unnecessary stages, since it's bad for performance. Good indicators of this are:

- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) followed by [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), usually means you can do this in one stage.
- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) followed by [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is probably going to get compacted by the "optimizer" anyway, but you "should" get in the habit of of combining the two.
- [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) followed by [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), should indicate that you probably should be using [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) in a single stage instead. Since you likely did the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to produce fields based on calculations, that were then considered in the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).

And finally:

- [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) before a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), really should have been a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) "before" the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). Since it does in fact work a lot faster to "filter" within the document, and also saves cost on processing the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), due to less output from already filtered content.

But one more:

- All of the "array" operations such as [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) and even the "set operators" should always be used "in-line" with each other, in cases where those are manipulating the same array content. The same now even applies to wrapping with [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) or [`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) now that these can work directly on arrays themselves, and often with the strange looking but effective:

  ```
  { "$sum": { "$sum": "$array" } }
  ```

  structure within a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and suggestions

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with the aggregation framework.
The query look like this:

```
Data.aggregate([
            { "$match": { "hid": hid } },
            { "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "sensors": {
                    "$filter": { "input": "$sensors", "as": "sensor", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$sensor.nid", nid ] } }
                },
                "actuators": {
                    "$filter": { "input": "$actuators", "as": "actuator", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$actuator.nid", nid ] } }
                },
                "status": {
                    "$filter": { "input": "$status", "as": "state", "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$state.nid", nid ] } }
                },
                "updated": 1,
                "created": 1
            }},
            { "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "sensors": {
                    "$slice": [ "$sensors", -10 ]
                },
                "actuators": {
                    "$slice": [ "$actuators", -10 ]
                },
                "status": {
                    "$slice": [ "$status", -10 ]
                },
                "updated": 1,
                "created": 1
            }}
        ]).exec(function(err,data) {
        });
```

It uses the `$match` to find the schema, the `$filter` to pick from the array only the elements that match the provided `nid` and then uses the `$slice` to pick the last 10 elements from the filtered array

Comment: Good that you came to your own conclusion here, but there are some structural problems here you should be aware of that have a large effect on performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and suggestions :)